# Error initializing excel application with win32com

Tags: python, excel, automation, win32com

I am trying to run a python script in a remote server desktop and I noticed my script breaks when tries to initialize the object:
`xlApp = win32.Dispatch('Excel.Application')`
. Locally everything runs fine, but on the server i get the error:

```
"C:\Users\admin.export\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 91, in _GetGoodDispatch
     IDispatch = pythoncom.CoCreateInstance(IDispatch, None, clsctx, pythoncom.IID_IDispatch)
 
 com_error: (-2147221005, 'Invalid class string', None, None)
```

- Anyone could help?
  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is Excel installed on the server?

Comment: I thought it was, but not eventually. That was the reason. Thank you @DS_London. Solved.